# Expected value of a Geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I have a random number $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$ and a value $Y\sim Poi(X)$. I have to calculate $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

I proved that $Y\sim Geo(\frac{\lambda}{(\lambda+1)})$, so i should have $\mathbb{E}[Y]:=\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda}$.

Why, instead, is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$?

Text says that $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[X]$. Trivially the first equivalence is a property of conditional expectation but what justifies the second equivalence?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Observe that $\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]=x$. This justifies the equality $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=X$. Taking expectations on both sides you find the second equality.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for your answer, now it's clear!

Comment: @drhab I've only a question for you because the same problem showed back up: $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]:=x$? Is it a definition? Thanks again!

Comment: No, I would not call it a definition. It is just the observation that under condition  $X=x$ random variable  $Y$ has Poisson distribution with parameter  $x$ so that the expectation of $Y$ under that condition equals  $x$.

Comment: @drhab All right! Really thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Conditioned on $\{X=x\}$, $Y$ has Poisson distribution with mean $x$. So we can compute the distribution of $Y$ by conditioning on $X$: for any nonnegative integer $n$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=n) &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(Y=n\mid X=x)f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac\lambda{n!} \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-(1+\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx.
\end{align}
We compute the integral $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-(1+\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx$ by induction. For $n=0$, 
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-(1+\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx = \frac1{1+\lambda} = \frac{0!}{(1+\lambda)^1}.
$$
Now suppose that $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-(1+\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx = \frac{n!}{(1+\lambda)^{n+1}}$ for some nonnegative integer $n$. Then using integration by parts, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{n+1} e^{-(1+\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx &= \left.\frac{-x^{n+1}e^{-(1+\lambda)x}}{1+\lambda}\right|_0^\infty +\frac{n+1}{1+\lambda}\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-(1+\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= 0 + \frac{n+1}{1+\lambda}\left(\frac{n!}{(1+\lambda)^{n+1}}\right)\\
&= \frac{(n+1)!}{(1+\lambda)^{n+2}}.
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\mathbb P(Y=n) = \frac\lambda{n!}\left(\frac{n!}{(1+\lambda)^{n+1}}\right) = \frac\lambda{(1+\lambda)^{n+1}}.
$$
We compute the mean of $Y$ by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot\mathbb P(Y=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\lambda}{(1+\lambda)^{n+1}}\\
&= \frac1\lambda.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that technically $Y|X\sim Poi(X)$. Then the second equivalence is using the expected value of a Poisson random variable.